# How to convert c# list to Jquery e-calendar events?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a jquery events calendar (e-calendar) in the front end and retrieving the events from SharePoint calendar (c#), how can I convert this c# code to be displayed in the jquery e-calendar events?

Jquery events calendar:
https://github.com/jhonis/e-calendar

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SPListItemCollection corporateCalendarListItems = GetCorporateCalendarItems();
            if (corporateCalendarListItems != null) { AddCorporateCalendarEventsToUI(corporateCalendarListItems); }
        }
    }

    private SPListItemCollection GetCorporateCalendarItems()
    {
        using (SPSite wadiSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb wadiWeb = wadiSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                wadiWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                // Fetch the List
                SPList corporateCalendarList = wadiWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Corporate Calendar");

                // Return the last item
                if (corporateCalendarList != null)
                {
                    DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Now;
                    string month = todayDate.ToString("MM");
                    string year = todayDate.ToString("yyyy");
                    string endOfMonthDate = year + "-" + month + "-30";
                    string startOfMonthDate = year + "-" + month + "-01";
                    SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
                    qry.Query = @"<Where><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category'  /><Value Type='Choice'>Holiday</Value></Eq><Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>"+startOfMonthDate+"</Value></Geq></And><Leq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + endOfMonthDate + "T12:00:00Z</Value></Leq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /></OrderBy>";
                    qry.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='Category' />";
                    SPListItemCollection corporateCalendarListItems = corporateCalendarList.GetItems(qry);

                    return corporateCalendarListItems;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddCorporateCalendarEventsToUI(SPListItemCollection corporateCalendarListItems)
    {
        List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents = new List<CalendarEvent>();

        foreach (SPListItem corporateCalendarListItem in corporateCalendarListItems)
        {
            CalendarEvent calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent();
            calendarEvent.Title = corporateCalendarListItem["Title"].ToString();

            if(corporateCalendarListItem["EventDate"] != null)
            {
                calendarEvent.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(corporateCalendarListItem["EventDate"].ToString());
            }
            if (corporateCalendarListItem["EndDate"] != null)
            {
                calendarEvent.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(corporateCalendarListItem["EndDate"].ToString());
            }
            calendarEvent.Category = "Test";
            calendarEvent.AllDay = false;

            calendarEvents.Add(calendarEvent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post some code so I can figure it out?

Comment: C# code:
private void AddEventsToUI(SPListItemCollection calendarItems){
List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents = new List<CalendarEvent>();
foreach (SPListItem calendarItem in calendarItems){
CalendarEvent calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent();
calendarEvent.Title = calendarItem["Title"].ToString();
calendarEvent.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(calendarItem["EventDate"].ToString());
calendarEvent.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(calendarItem["EndDate"].ToString());
                calendarEvents.Add(calendarEvent); } }

Jquery events calendar:
https://github.com/jhonis/e-calendar

Comment: Move your code from comment section and add it into your post (where your have asked the question).

Comment: Done adding code to the post